# How do I support large screens with low densities?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-resources, android-screen-support

I provide drawables for different densities (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc.) and they work fine, but a 10-inch 1280 x 800 tablet is not very high density (150dp?) and so I get relatively low-density drawables scaled up to a large size. It doesn't look good.

My app is already larger than I would like, so I want to avoid copying more drawables into a bunch of different `drawable-large-mdpi`, `drawable-large-ldpi`, etc. folders.

I don't know how many screens today are still ldpi and mdpi, but I want to support smaller screens while still looking good on large screens, even large screens that are lower density. Is there a standard or recommended approach to this?

Comment: Maybe `mipmap` could help

Comment: surely your png drawables are 9-patch?

Comment: @NannuoLei, Actually, I just use different size png files for the various screen densities. I never quite understood 9-patch, but I just looked it up and it looks good for things like buttons, but my drawables are more complex (characters, landscapes, etc.).